# Constant 401 error with OAuth1 (MCM API)

Tags: java, android, oauth, oauth-1.0a

I've been trying to establish a connection with an API for more than a week now, to no avail. (Magic Card Market's, authentification documentation [here](https://www.mkmapi.eu/ws/documentation/API:Auth_OAuthHeader) and [there](https://www.mkmapi.eu/ws/documentation/API:Auth_OAuthHeader)). I'm supposed to receive a XML file.

I have what MCM call a "widget" access to their API, meaning that I don't have nor need a oauth_token (it's supposed to be an empty string) for the authorization header, and that I'm not supposed to receive nor use an access token/access secret.

The only things I do have are a consumer key (they call it app token sometimes) and a consumer secret.

Here is how I build my Authorization header :

```
private static String buildOAuthAuthorization(String method, String request)
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {

    String mkmAppToken = APICredentials.appToken;
    String mkmAppSecret = APICredentials.appSecret;

    String realm = "https://www.mkmapi.eu/ws/v1.1/games";
    String oauthVersion = "1.0";
    String oauthConsumerKey = mkmAppToken;
    String oauthToken = "";
    String oauthSignatureMethod = "HMAC-SHA1";
    String oauthTimestamp = Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
    String oauthNonce = Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis());

    String paramString = "oauth_consumer_key=" + oauthConsumerKey
            + "oauth_nonce=" + oauthNonce
            + "oauth_signature_method=" + oauthSignatureMethod
            + "oauth_timestamp=" + oauthTimestamp
            + "oauth_token=" + oauthToken
            + "oauth_version=" + oauthVersion;

    String baseString = method + "&" + rawUrlEncode(realm) + "&" + rawUrlEncode(paramString);

    String signingKey = rawUrlEncode(mkmAppSecret) + "&";

    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HMAC-SHA1");
    SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(signingKey.getBytes(), mac.getAlgorithm());
    mac.init(secret);
    byte[] digest = mac.doFinal(baseString.getBytes());
    byte[] oauthSignature = Base64.encode(digest, Base64.URL_SAFE);

    String authorizationProperty = "OAuth "
            + "realm=\"" + realm + "\", "
            + "oauth_version=\"" + oauthVersion + "\", "
            + "oauth_timestamp=\"" + oauthTimestamp + "\", "
            + "oauth_nonce=\"" + oauthNonce + "\", "
            + "oauth_consumer_key=\"" + oauthConsumerKey + "\", "
            + "oauth_token=\""+ oauthToken + "\", "
            + "oauth_signature_method=\"" + oauthSignatureMethod + "\", "
            + "oauth_signature=\"" + oauthSignature + "\"";

    System.out.println(authorizationProperty);

    return authorizationProperty;
}
```

The actual request is in an AsyncTask :

```
public static class oAuthRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, StringReader> {

    private int lastCode;

    @Override
    protected StringReader doInBackground(String... requestURLs) {

        String method = requestURLs[0];
        String url = requestURLs[1];
        StringReader result = null;

        try {

            String authProperty = buildOAuthAuthorization(method, url);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
            connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization:", authProperty);

            lastCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("RESPONSE CODE 1 " + lastCode);

            // Get content
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(lastCode == 200 ? connection.getInputStream() : connection.getErrorStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            rd.close();
            result = new StringReader(sb.toString());

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

It seems like no matter what I change, I'm always getting a 401.

Things I've tried :

- oauthSignature as a String using Base64.encodeToString()
- Nonce generation using SecureRandom
- With and without the empty oauthToken
- Another timestamp generation method (can't remember what though)
- signing key with and without app token (theorically I need only the consumer secret, but you never know)
- Using HttpsURLConnection instead of HttpURLConnection (the URI start in https, so I thought, hey. But no)
- At least 2-3 other different implementations (one who was basically a copy/paste of the Java example in the documentation of course -- it still kind of is one now)
- (Probably a lot of things I can't even remember)

At this point I'm wondering if maybe the issue comes from my keys, as I've tried to use the Postman app to test requests with the same results.

Comment: I'm working with the same API, via a Dedicated App right now though. For the games overview I needed both app and access tokens to access it, I understand you don't have access tokens with a widget though. Have you tried other resources? Like information of a specific card for example. In summary I think the API is quite a pain to work with. Additional question, how long did it take for you to get our Widget App keys?

Comment: I suspect the issue is in `rawUrlEncode` as that also gave me various issues, can you post the code for that?

Comment: did you ever get this working?